# Elegant way to add and set property by condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating data object to send with Ajax to the server. I find myself repeating these lines to add properties to data object:

```
var param1, param2;
if (param1 = $("field1").val())
  data.param1 = param1;

if (param2 = $("field2").val())
  data.param2 = param2;

etc.
```

I am just curious if there's any more elegant way to fill data object in my case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a setter function:

```
data.set = function(key, value, fieldName){
    if(value = $(fieldName).val()){    
        this[key] = this[value]
    }
}
```

then you would just call data.set('param1', param1, 'field1);

This is not a fix per se but just a shorter way of putting it

Comment: Thanks, I just would like to notice - I am not comparing in "if". I am setting param to the value and it returns true if this value is not undefined/empty.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i thought you've just mistyped